# Богомильство и латинянство можно изгнать? из владений?

Tags: точное-словоупотребление

> Стефан неустанно поддерживает духовенство и борется с ересями –
>   изгоняет богомильство и латинянство из своих владений.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Стефан неустанно поддерживает духовенство и борется с ересями – **изгоняет** богомильство и латинянство из своих владений.

Толковый словарь Ефремовой

https://slovar.cc/rus/efremova-tolk/289563.html

ИЗГОНЯТЬ

1) а) Заставлять уйти; выгонять, прогонять.

б) Вынуждать покинуть родину, оставить дом.

в) С боем вытеснять противника с занятой территории.

2) перен. **Устранять, исключать; решительно избавляться от чего-л.**

Ефремова. Толковый словарь Ефремовой. 2012